# Timeout handling in Neo4j .NET Bolt driver

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to set timeouts of the sockets used by the Neo4j .NET Bolt driver? I'd like the Bolt session to throw an exception if for any reason it runs too long.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j team asked to me to file a ticket so they will develop this "enhancement": https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7344